# Получение атрибутов файла, папки или диска

Tags: файлы, java

Требуется создать java апплет со свойствами:

- Апплет предназначен для запуска с html страницы (в том числе не должно быть препятствий для использования на защищенных страницах - https).
- у апплета не должно быть видимой части на странице.
- доступ к функциям апплета с помощью javascript с html страницы.
- апплет должен предоставлять браузеру функцию readDir (string pDir) для перечисления файлов и папок по указанному пути с локального компьютера пользователя в качестве входного параметра функции.
- Если входной параметр функции передан в апплет пустой строкой, то следует вернуть список элементов из папки "Мой компьютер" (список съемных и несъемных носителей).
- функция readDir возвращает объект, у которого есть две функции: getCount() и getItem(number).
- getCount() возвращает кол-во элементов найденных в папке.
- getItem(number) - возвращает элемент с номером number.
- функция getItem должна возвращать объект, содержащий сведения о: имени файла, типе файла (папка, диск или файл), размере файла в байтах, дате создания, дате изменения. Для получения каждого значения из объекта - отдельная функция.

Вот код который я начал создавать:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

class FileInfo {
   public static String NameFile;
   public static String TypeFile;
   public static int SizeFile;
   public static Date DateCreate;
   public static Date DateEdit;
}

public class View_files_folders 
{
   static String pach;
   private int count = 0;
   
   public FileInfo getItem(int number)
   {
      FileInfo FI = new FileInfo();
      File file = new File(pach);
      int c = 0;
      
      File[] s = file.listFiles();
      for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
      {   
        c++;
        if (c==number)
        {
          FI.NameFile = file.getName();
          //FI.TypeFile = "";
          FI.SizeFile = (int) file.length();
          //FI.DateCreate = "";
          //FI.DateEdit = "";
        }       
      } 
      return FI;   
   }
   
   public int getCount()
   {
    /* Подсчет всех файлов и
     папок в каталоге
    */
    File file = new File(pach);
    File[] s = file.listFiles();
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
    {   
      count++;
    }   
    return count;      
   }
   
   public int getAllCount()
   {
      /* Подсчет всех файлов и 
       папок во всех содержащихся 
       подкаталогах
      */
      File file = new File(pach);
      File[] s = file.listFiles();
      for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
      {
         if (s[j].isDirectory())
         { 
            pach = s[j].getPath();
            getAllCount();  
         }
         count++;
      }
      return count;
   }
}
```

Вопросы следующие возникли:

1. Как в функции getItem узнать тип файла (то есть папка, файл или диск это)?
2. Как в ней же узнать дату создания файла и дату модификации (соответственно поля FI.DateCreate и FI.DateEdit)?
3. Как узнать где находится папка "Мой компьютер", в разных ОС и версиях разная директория?

Comment: ни в unix подобных системах, ни в Виндовс папки "Мой компьютер" не существует.
Наверное Вы имели ввыду, на каком логическом диске установленна система??!
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Я следую из технического задания, там написано: "Если входной параметр функции передан в апплет пустой строкой, то следует вернуть список элементов из папки "Мой компьютер" (список съемных и несъемных носителей)." Список дисков и съемных носителей я понимаю под "мой компьютер". Насчет этого у меня затруднения...

Comment: Судя по всему, человек, который составлял ТЗ, настолько неграмотен, что не знает, что бывает не только Windows. У Windows каталог «Мой Компьютер» виртуальный, он доступен лишь при обращении через системно-зависимые функции shell'а.

Вместо этого просто сделайте свой «виртуальный» объект, который при перечислении будет выдавать список дисков. Обратите внимание, что в Unix-подобных системах у файловой системы единый корень (съёмные устройства монтируются «в середину» файловой системы, а не параллельно ей, как на Windows), так что вам придётся отдельно продумать имплементацию в этом случае.

Comment: тут я с вами Влад согласен)

Answer (score 6):

```
file.isFile() // это файл
file.isDirectory() // или это папка
new Date(file.lastModified()) // дата последней модификации
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если это диск, а не файл или папка, то тут как быть? И насчет даты создания файла тоже вопрос.

Comment: Вернет null, если это корневая директория

    String path = "С:";
    File root = new File(path);
    System.out.println(root.getParent());

Answer (score 3):

Для получения списка дисков и съемных носителей:

```
File[] arrayRoots = File.listRoots();
for (File root : arrayRoots) {
  System.out.println(root.getPath());
}
```

Comment: спасибо, за пример хороший